# CSS3 nested calc function using multiply and vw not rendering

Tags: css, calc

I've done some mathematics to find the series of a certain element in the background of my current website. I've narrowed down the precise location to:

```
bottom: calc((737px - ((100vw / 200px) * 64px)) + 70px)
```

But in Chrome, the developer tool has crossed it out as unrenderable.

I'm wondering what point in this calculation has failed?

Comment: you cannot divide with a unit and you cannot multiple two units. Ask your self a question : what does it mean `vw/px`? what will be unit of the result

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd imaging it'd be the same as using something like `calc(100% / 3)` in CSS.

Comment: dividing 100% by 3 is 33.33%, this is math and logical .. dividing vw with px has no meaning. Imagine you want to divide a paper into 3 (logical and doable) then imagine you want to divide a paper with a pen, what does it mean? what will be the result? a paper, a pen, something else?

Comment: Could you describe what functionality are you trying to obtain? I'm pretty sure there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to expect the browser to figure out how much `200px` (respectively `64px`) is, as a ratio, from current browser width and automatically use that value.

Current browser implementation of `calc` only allows multiplication and division with numbers:

```
... : calc(100vw / 3) // valid
... : calc(1200px / 3) // valid
... : calc(1200vw / 200px) // NOT valid
```

See `calc()` [current definition](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation).

Comment: Was just a simple syntax error that I glossed over from previous coding. Thanks for your long explanation.